# Creating mesh from a simple point cloud

Tags: mesh

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to create mesh from a point cloud, and currently having trouble finding the right parameters/methods to get good result. I have created point cloud (sampled from a, plane extracted from, kinect scan) in a structured way where the points are in a grid.

When I generate a mesh using pcl::GreedyProjectionTriangulation, I see that points are beng used just once, and hence the mesh I am getting is simply set of triangels all separated. Please see the two pics, pointCloud:


and Mesh (I want a mesh where there are no gaps. I can easily create a ply format file for this since this is a plane, but it would be difficult to create it for complex point clouds. I am sure there already is a method to do so.

, where mesh is being displayed in meshlab (I convereted vtk to ply by using a custom code).

Please let me know what parameters to use.

My i/p point cloud have two points separated by 0.025 meters.
The parameter for mesh are: (I am not able to see any difference on changing these)

```
p_setKSearch: 20
p_setSearchRadius: 0.1
p_setMu: 5
p_neighbours: 100
p_maxSurfAnglePiDiv: 4
p_minAnglePiDiv: 18
p_maxAnglePiDiv: 1.5
p_normal_consist: true
```

The code I am using to convertPointCLoud to Mehs is:

void CreateWorld::createMeshFromCloud(pcl::PointCloud::Ptr &ipCloudI){

```
//Let's first convert it to PointXYZ
pcl::PointCloud<pointType>::Ptr cloud = getXYZfromRGB(ipCloudI); //pointType is pointXYZ

pcl::NormalEstimation<pointType, pcl::Normal> n;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr normals (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);

pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>);
tree->setInputCloud (cloud);
n.setInputCloud (cloud);
n.setSearchMethod (tree);
n.setKSearch (ParamValue::p_setKSearch);        //It was 20
n.compute (*normals);                //Normals are estimated using standard method.


// Concatenate the XYZ and normal fields*
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal>::Ptr cloud_with_normals (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal>);
pcl::concatenateFields (*cloud, *normals, *cloud_with_normals);
//* cloud_with_normals = cloud + normals

// Create search tree*
pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointNormal>::Ptr tree2 (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointNormal>);
tree2->setInputCloud (cloud_with_normals);

// Initialize objects
pcl::GreedyProjectionTriangulation<pcl::PointNormal> gp3;
pcl::PolygonMesh triangles;

// Set the maximum distance between connected points (maximum edge length)
gp3.setSearchRadius (ParamValue::p_setSearchRadius);            //It was 0.025

// Set typical values for the parameters
gp3.setMu (ParamValue::p_setMu);                                            //It was 2.5
gp3.setMaximumNearestNeighbors (ParamValue::p_neighbours);    //It was 100
gp3.setMaximumSurfaceAngle(M_PI/ParamValue::p_maxSurfAnglePiDiv); // 45 degrees    //it was 4
gp3.setMinimumAngle(M_PI/ParamValue::p_minAnglePiDiv); // 10 degrees        //It was 18
gp3.setMaximumAngle(M_PI/ParamValue::p_maxAnglePiDiv); // 120 degrees        //it was 1.5
gp3.setNormalConsistency(ParamValue::p_normal_consist);                    //It was false

// Get result
gp3.setInputCloud (cloud_with_normals);
gp3.setSearchMethod (tree2);
gp3.reconstruct (triangles);

// Additional vertex information
std::vector<int> parts = gp3.getPartIDs();
std::vector<int> states = gp3.getPointStates();
//pcl::io::
pcl::io::saveVTKFile (ParamValue::planeMeshVTK, triangles);

std::cout<<"\n\n\t Calling conversion from VTK to PLY";
convertVtkToPly(ParamValue::planeMeshVTK, ParamValue::planeMeshPLY);
```

}

Any help/pointer is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Nirala A K

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6874/creating-mesh-from-a-simple-point-cloud/) by [aknirala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/475/aknirala/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You'll be able to get help on this much faster if you post it to the [PCL mailing list](http://www.pcl-users.org/). Luckily it is very active.

Also, if you don't need to do this programmatically, creating the mesh in MeshLab instead of PCL would be much easier. [Here](http://meshlabstuff.blogspot.com/2009/09/meshing-point-clouds.html) and [here](http://gmv.cast.uark.edu/scanning/point-clouds-to-mesh-in-meshlab/) are some tutorials on how to do that.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/559/airuno2l/) with karma: 26 on 2014-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/475/aknirala/) on 2014-08-29**:
Thanks Arinuo, I did posted there http://www.pcl-users.org/Creating-mesh-from-a-simple-point-cloud-td4035178.html got no reply. 
 It would be good if I could get this done via code. I am going through the tutorial you pointed though.

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/475/aknirala/) on 2014-08-29**:
Thanks Arinuo,